# What's wrong with my ternary `if` expression?

Tags: c++, loops

i understand that the conditional operator `?` can be used to simplify the `if` conditional but i'm really having  a hard time with it, is it possible to use it as a loop ? for example in the code here it keeps telling me that i can not use `r` as a function what exactly am i missing ?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define PI 3.14159

int main () {  
    double r,circle,o;  
    int rmax =0;
    int n;
    cout << "enter the number of  circles:";
    cin >> n;
    (n > 1) ? cin >> r (r > rmax) ? rmax = r : r=r: cout<<rmax; 
}
```

Comment: This is a terrible use for a ternary operator. If you're shooting for obfuscation, you hit your mark.

Comment: That last line doesn't look simple at all. Why not write it as an `if` first so we understand what you're trying to do. Also, there's no such thing as an `if` "loop".

Comment: this bit here `r (r > rmax)` looks to the compiler like a function call

Comment: If you **really** **really** want to use ternary operators, put everything in brackets.(This will fix your problem here).

Comment: @NikitaDemodov yeah problem is that i can only use ternary operators in this exact problem thx for the help

Comment: @Calculuswhiz yep

Comment: @lololol -maybe you can explain what you are trying to achieve. If this is an exercise in using the ternary operator for some "quiz" then that helps a lot with our answers - most people will probably advise against using ternary operator like this otherwise : )

Comment: @code_fodder not a quiz but trying to learn how to use ternary for an upcoming quiz, why is it bad though ? from what learned it can simplify conditional operators like `if`.

Comment: it *can* if used in certain circumstances. But it is not *always* better. Certainly, in my opinion, if your single line gets so complicated that you can't read it in a glace, then it may well be better of written in long-form - clear and simple (IMO) is almost always better - even if that means more lines. For example - you can write an entire program in one line if that is your goal! - its just not recommended  : )

Comment: What loop are you talking about? All I see is a conditional statement.

Comment: @code_fodder you are right and i honestly i would rather use `if` but our instructor wants from my class to use ternary operators during the first half of this course so i really must get used to using it.

Comment: @Caleb i was trying to create an input loop using it so that as long as `n` is bigger than 1 it keeps making user input a number but at this point i just wanted to understand how to solve this problem with ternary.

Comment: @lololol Maybe you could re-title your question *What's wrong with my ternary expression?* or similar, because the talk about a loop is a confusing distraction when a) there's no loop, and b) there's no such thing as an "if loop", at least in C++. (And that's saying something, because there's very little that doesn't exist somewhere in C++.)

Comment: @Caleb oh my god didn't see that i wrote an `if` loop sorry for confusion its late into the night here :( and you are right it's a fetal mistake

Comment: @Caleb I've lost count of the number of times I've seen beginners call any statement with a body a "loop". They don't realize that "loop" means something that repeats (maybe they're not native English speakers, or they just don't recognize the metaphor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ternary operator (`?:`) can be easier described using a function:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
T &ternary(bool a, T &b, T &c) {
    if (a)
        return b;
    else
        return c;
}

int main() {
    // The behavior is not completely equivalent
    // This example just explains the basic concept of the ternary operator
    std::cout << ternary(true, 5, 2) << '\n';
    std::cout << (true ? 5 : 2) << '\n';
}
```

The expression `condition ? value1 : value2` returns either `value1` or `value2` depending on `condition`.

Of course, `value1` and `value2` can also be complex expressions but you have to remember to handle the returned values.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a;
    std::cout << (true ? a = 5 : 2) << '\n';
}
```

Both possible values must have the same type.

Your expression would look like:

```
ternary((n > 1), cin >> r ternary((r > rmax), rmax = r, r=r), cout<<rmax);
```

Now the problem should be obvious.

Comment: so basically what you are saying is that both `value1` and `value2` should be of the same type like if iam returning an `int value1` then `value2` should be an `int` as well ?

Comment: The main problem is there is no operator between `r` and `ternary` resp. `r` and `(r > max)`

Comment: Ah i see now that's why the its seeing it as a function thank so much!!

Comment: @lololol - just to re-iterate my point - you probably would not have made that mistake using if/else and multiple lines - because its much easier to read and debug : )

Comment: The `ternary()` function is not equivalent to the conditional operator because it evaluates both `b` and `c` regardless of the condition. It can't be used when they have side effects or the validity depends on the condition.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, you are right. There are differences. But some people understand the basic concept of ternary operators after this example.